# How to configure included protocols using Camel's JettyHttpComponent?

Tags: java, ssl, https, jetty, apache-camel

I want to disable these protocols SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and allow only TLSv1.2.

So far I've dig up that SslContextFactory has includedProtocols property but this class is deprecated.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option sslContextParametersRef to setup customer sslContextParameters like this.

```
...
  <camel:sslContextParameters
      id="sslContextParameters">
    <camel:keyManagers
        keyPassword="keyPassword">
      <camel:keyStore
          resource="/users/home/server/keystore.jks"
          password="keystorePassword"/>
    </camel:keyManagers>

   <camel:secureSocketProtocols>
     <camel:secureSocketProtocol>TLSv1.2</camel:secureSocketProtocol>
   </camel:secureSocketProtocols>

  </camel:sslContextParameters>...
...
  <to uri="jetty:https://127.0.0.1/mail/?sslContextParametersRef=sslContextParameters"/>
...
```

Comment: I tried with that but i am getting:  Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite. Can you please help me on this ?